# How to chunk multiple user_id together to form another column in a data.table?

Tags: r, dplyr

I need to group and sort my primary key (user_id) together by chunking them together. So, I need to introduce a new column that sort of act like a counter. Essentially, I need to make something like this:

```
chunk_user |   user    |     item     |
1          |  200401   |    78832     |
1          |  200401   |    95718     |
1          |  200401   |    24161     |
2          |  200402   |    12437     |
2          |  200402   |    61490     |
2          |  200402   |    45956     |
```

from something like this:

```
user id | isbn | rating
    123 | 4567 | 2
    129 | 7890 | 3
    127 | 4450 | 0
    123 | 9972 | 1
```

I tried using the group_by() to start but not only it doesn't work like the way I wanted, it doesn't even sort my data properly.

```
table_rated <- tbl_ratings %>% group_by(user_id) %>% arrange(isbn, ratings, sort = TRUE)
```

I really appreciate any help!

Comment: Hi WLRY, it's not clear to me how you go from the second table to the first. You say you just want to introduce a new column, but none of the columns in the two tables match.

Comment: I'm sorry for not clarifying my question. The first table is just an example from the textbook. I wanted my dataset. to look like that, where similar user ID are grouped together under one user_chunk and so on.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's not entirely clear, but this may be close to what you're looking for.

You can use `rleid` from `data.table` to enumerate different `user_id`s.

When using `arrange` you can include `.by_group` to sort first by the grouping variable.

Let me know if this is what you had in mind.

```
library(tidyverse)
library(data.table)

tbl_ratings %>%
  group_by(user_id) %>%
  arrange(isbn, rating, .by_group = T) %>%
  ungroup %>%
  mutate(chunk_user = rleid(user_id))
```

**Output**

```
  user_id  isbn rating chunk_user
    <dbl> <dbl>  <int>      <int>
1     123  4567      2          1
2     123  9972      1          1
3     127  4450      0          2
4     129  7890      3          3
```

Comment: Yes! Thank you so much, Ben! This was exactly what I needed. All I needed to do was giving it a name and changed it into a data.table structure. I really appreciate your help. Hope you have a nice day!